# How do I generate reports in Java?

Tags: java, sql, report, reportgenerator

How do I generate reports in Java using IO?

I want to generate PDF files with database records.

At the moment I have something like this...

```
try{
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Desktop/Test.pdf");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    out.writeChars("Name of user: ");
    out.writeChars("Age: ");
    out.close();
}
}
    catch (IOException ioe){
    }
```

It keeps saying that the PDF file is corrupted.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

Edit: I do not want to use iReports/JasperReports/iText/other report generators.

Many thanks

Comment: Use [itext](http://itextpdf.com/) to generate real PDF files. Another option may be using Jasper Reports and iReports designer, from [jaspersoft](http://community.jaspersoft.com/). Disclaimer: I'm not attached to this company, it is proposed by mere experience working with this technology.

Comment: why do you think ObjectOutputStream can magically generate pdf?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please read the Edit bit. I did mention that I dont want to use report generators. I want to generate the file through pure 'raw' coding.

Comment: You know, these are open source libraries. Just open the source of one of them and see how they use the code to generate a PDF file. Also, a PDF **IS NOT** a text file, why did you ever think that would work?

Comment: @user2525364 A PDF is a file [with a specific format](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf). You cannot just write text to a file, this makes a `.txt`. If you want to use "raw coding" to generate PDFs then good luck with that.

Answer (score 6):

Well, first of all, if you don't want to use any of the java PDF/reporting libraries, you have to understand what is a PDF.

Start [here with an article about the structure of a PDF](https://planetpdf.com/navigating-the-internal-structure-of-a-pdf-document/), then go [here for the complete, raw reference of the PDF format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference.pdf).

Hint: this is *very hard*. PDF is a print/display-oriented format and really complex. Another option is generating an HTML and using some tool to generate the PDF in the end. This is usually easier, as HTML is a far simpler format than PDF.

HTH!

Comment: you may find this link useful too, mister massa http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF :-) BTW, don't forget April's 12th :-)

Comment: Bah, whats hard about a 1300 pages spec :)

Comment: The first link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Try itex API. To use IText PDF API for Java you must first download the IText JAR file from the IText website (http://itextpdf.com/), and include it on your application class path:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/getting-started.html